# SumConvergence[((-1)^n)/(Sqrt[n] + (-1)^n), n] returns True in Version 10.2?

Tags: bugs, summation

**Bug introduced in 10.4.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

I claim that the series
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}$
diverges. To see this, rewrite the $n^{th}$ term as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n} = 
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n} \times \frac{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^{n+1}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
= \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}+(-1)^{2n+1}}{n+(-1)^{2n+1}} = 
\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n-1} + \frac{-1}{n-1}
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n} = 
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n-1} - 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
\end{equation*}
Now, we have the difference of two series. The first series, by the Alternating Series Test, is convergent, and the second is the well known divergent harmonic series.

However,

```
    SumConvergence[((-1)^n)/(Sqrt[n] + (-1)^n), n]
```

returns True, and

```
    N[Sum[((-1)^n)/(Sqrt[n] + (-1)^n), {n, 2, Infinity}]]
```

returns -2.70244.

To add some evidence for the divergence of the series, the code

```
    pow10 = 10;
    expo = 1;
    While[ expo <= 6,
      Print [N[Sum[((-1)^n)/(Sqrt[n] + (-1)^n), {n, 2, pow10}]]];
      expo++;
      pow10 *= 10;
    ]
```

returns

```
    -1.74377
    -4.21214
    -6.55378
    -8.86764
    -11.1737
    -13.4774
```

I see in another post that there was an issue with *SumConvergence* in version 10.0.0.0, but I am using Version 10.2. Any insights here?

Comment: I believe you are right. I note that `NSum` using the AlternatingSigns method yields a slightly different result as the one above for `Sum`: `NSum[((-1)^n)/(Sqrt[n] + (-1)^n), {n, 2, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]` ==> -2.67892. `Sum` with a finite limit yields the same set of results as your loop does.

Comment: But if a sum is conditionally convergent (which *if* that sum converges, it will be conditionally convergent), if you rearrange the sum, you can get a different value for the limit (and you can rearrange it to get infinity), so rearranging it and getting infinity is not evidence for that sum not converging.

Comment: In fact, maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, but doesn't this sum *also* converge by the Alternating Series Test? Maybe it's the *decreasing monotonically* part that's missing...

Comment: @march It is missing that. Without *rearranging*, but just *grouping* the elements of the series pairwise we find `a[2n]+a[2n+1]` to be negative for all natural `n`, the partial sums very quickly get below -2.67892, and the positive element of the pair of two neighboring elements is never sufficient to bring it even close to the supposed limit.

Comment: By the way, OP did not *rearrange* the sum either. He did put it in a more convenient form. I'm not sure if splitting a series `Sum[a[n] + b[n]]` into `Sum[a[n]]` and `Sum[b[n]]` qualifies as rearrangement.

Comment: @ LLlAMnYP I agree that rearrangement is a problem when determining the actual value of a conditionally convergent series, but it is not a problem when determining whether a series converges.

Comment: Plotting partial sums versus the log of maximum n converges to a nice straight line, suggesting logarithmic divergence. Treacherous territory.

Comment: As far as I know `Sum(a[n]+b[n]) = Sum[a[n]]+Sum[b[n]]`  only holds when the single sums converge

Comment: It now returns unevaluated in MMA 11.0.0.

Comment: This is a convergent, but not absolutely convergent, series. See [Absolute convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) and [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) for info.

Comment: This is not any bug. See the answers of Валерий Заподовников and me for explanation.

Comment: The discussion in the comments of conditional/absolute convergence is not relevant. Convergence is the same as the existence of the limit of the partial sum. Given any two sequences and their sum or difference, consider their series: if any two converge, then the third must converge also; thus if any one of them diverge, at least one of the others must diverge, since this is true for limits. So the OP's reasoning is correct.

Comment: @user64494 I do not agree this is not a bug. This is a bug, but may be very hard to fix. Michael E2, it is not an obvious result moreover you can just use Tailor (link is FOR this series, diverges) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423121/is-sum-n-2-infty-frac-1n-sqrt-n-1n-convergent/2423137#2423137

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников It seems quite elementary to me. No need for Taylor series. If $a_n=b_n+c_n$, $\sum b_n$ diverges, and $\sum c_n$ converges, $\sum a_n$ must diverge; for if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum (a_n-c_n)$ must also converge contrary to the divergence of $\sum b_n$.

Comment: That is how you prove it, yes (checked my testbook). No grouping or rearangment occurs, so you are right.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to rewrite the series:

```
Sum[((-1)^n)/(Sqrt[n] + (-1)^n), {n, 2, 1001}] ==
 Sum[1/(Sqrt[2 n] + 1) - 1/(Sqrt[2 n + 1] - 1), {n, 1, 500}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
SumConvergence[((-1)^n)/(Sqrt[n] + (-1)^n), n]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
SumConvergence[1/(Sqrt[2 n] + 1) - 1/(Sqrt[2 n + 1] - 1), n]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

( v 10.1 )

This is not rearranging terms, but grouping in pairs; the series are the same:

[image]

Comment: So, I assume you conclude that we see a bug here?

Comment: Rearranging terms is a big no-no for infinite sums though. Like @march said, the series might be conditionally convergent, although the OP is rather convincing.

Comment: beyond my expertise to prove or disprove (at least in a few minutes). I concur the OP's argument looks convincing.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries   I would conclude that there is a bug here. By the way, this is a problem from Tom Apostol's excellent, but nowadays out of favor (due to it's rigor) "Calculus, 2e". The answer for the problem is "divergent."

Comment: @clburchard When there is agreement  about this we can add the "bugs" tag to your question. Done now.

Comment: Let the partial sum be p[n_]:= Sum[1/( 1 + (-1)^k Sqrt[k]), {k,2,n}]. Then we find numerically that Sqrt[ Log[n] ] > | p[n] | > Log[n] from n>n0 where n0 is some value about 20 or so. So the series is divergent.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP If we let $s_n$ be the partial sum up to the term with index $n$, then george2079's grouping produces a series with partial sum $s_{2n+1}$ up to the odd index $2n+1$. So his partial sums are a subsequence of the original $s_n$. If $\lim s_n=L$, then we must have $\lim s_{2n+1}=L$. By contraposition if $s_{2n+1}$ diverges, then the original must diverge. The third result above is correct. — This grouping of consecutive terms is a standard intro calc trick. I don't know why Mma does not try it (still doesn't in V13.1).

Comment: Yes, this works too, because if a grouping of series is divergent, the series can be only divergent. (In fact you created a new series where each term is just two terms combined.) Why? Because when you group a convergent series you can only get convergent series with the same sum. When you group a divergent series you can get convergent or divergent series. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Just wow. So slightly different $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}$  is a classic example of (conditionally) convergent series for which Leibniz test fails. Leibniz test's monotonicity is NOT a necessary condition, thus the test itself is only sufficient, but not necessary! This is a very important result, because the test includes main nessessary condition for all series!

As for your variant of this series... It is also an example. See (diverges by Tailor): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4221590 It is actually a bad idea to use something like this (but it is correct, sum of divergent and convergent series is always divergent) since if it is conditionally convergent you can always rearrange the terms to make it divergent ([Riemann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)) and thus sometimes vice versa is possible. So... Use Tailor instead and it is divergent, yes:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2423137

There are other examples of such series with now absolute convergence. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073294/756502

I am not surprised Mathematica fails with these. They should really be remembered. Even this fails, but on Alpha it works:

```
a[n_] := ((-1)^n)/(n + (-1)^n);
SumConvergence[a[n], n]
```

Also see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1858185/756502

Comment: Two additional links are [Absolute convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) and [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) .

Comment: BTW, Alpha is also really buggy: it can print two different results (one being complex on first run) when you go to and F5 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%28-1%29%5En%2F%28n+%2B%28-1%29%5En%29+for+n+from+2+to+infinity while it only prints complex for https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%28-1%29%5En%2F%28Sqrt%28n%29+%2B%28-1%29%5En%29+for+n+from+2+to+infinity

Comment: Look at `DiscretePlot[Sum[(-1)^n/((-1)^n + Sqrt[n]), {n, 2, k}], {k, 500, 530}]` and `DiscretePlot[Sum[(-1)^n/((-1)^n + Sqrt[n]), {n, 2, k}], {k, 5000, 5030}]`

Comment: What about those? BTW, first link two comments above no longer prints strange stuff after F5, but second is still printing complex result. -4.92268 - 8.54584×10^-14 I