# Consecutive neighbours of Hypergeometric ${}_1 F_1(a,b,z)$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am working with the hypergeometric function ${}_1 F_1(a,b;z)$, where $a\in \mathbb{N^+}$, $b=2$, and $z\in \mathbb{C}$. The Wolfram function repository lists the following [relation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/17/01/01/)

$$\begin{equation}
{}_1 F_1(a,b;z)=\frac{(1-b)(b+z-2)}{(a-b+1)z}F_1(a,b-1;z)+\frac{(1-b)(2-b)}{(a-b+1)z}F_1(a,b-2;z)
\end{equation}$$

with no restrictions on $a,b$ and $z$. My question is how to implement this relation for $b=2$. I see the limit of the second term is well defined and it is 0, but the first term alone does not numerically agree with the left hand side.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Likely a bug in the documentation.

Comment: For $b=2$ you need to take the limit $b\to2$ in the second term on the right-hand side. Simply setting $b=2$ won't work because $_1F_1(a,0;z)$ is infinite.

Comment: Mathematica expression: `Hypergeometric1F1[a,b,z]-(1-b)*(b+z-2)/((a-b+1)*z)*Hypergeometric1F1[a,b-1,z]-(1-b)*(2-b)/((a-b+1)*z)*Hypergeometric1F1[a,b-2,z]`

Comment: @Roman: `Limit[(1 - b)*(2 - b)/((a - b + 1)*z)*Hypergeometric1F1[a, b - 2, z], 
 b -> 2]` results in `0`. Did you read "see the limit of the second term is well defined and it is 0" in the question?

Comment: @user64494 That limit is not actually zero. Take say `f[a_,b_,z_]:=(1-b)*(2-b)/((a-b+1)*z)*Hypergeometric1F1[a,b-2,z];
Plot[f[1/2,b,1/2],{b,1.5,2.5}]`.

Comment: @Roman: Therefore, we have a bug in  `Limit[(1 - b)*(2 - b)/((a - b + 1)*z)*Hypergeometric1F1[a, b - 2, z],   b -> 2]`.

Comment: The result of `a = 2; Plot3D[
 Hypergeometric1F1[a, b, z] - (1 - b)*(b + z - 2)/((a - b + 1)*z)*
   Hypergeometric1F1[a, b - 1, z] - (1 - b)*(2 - b)/((a - b + 1)*z)*
   Hypergeometric1F1[a, b - 2, z], {z, 0, 1}, {b, 1, 3}]` confirms the relation in the documentation in the case `a=2;`.

Comment: `Plot[b*Hypergeometric1F1[2, b, 1.2], {b, -1.1, 1.1}]` suggests that limit is nonzero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $c\approx0$ we can use a series-expansion for the second term on the right-hand side:
$$
_1F_1(a,c;z) = \frac{a z}{c}{_1}F_1(a+1,2;z)+O(1)
$$
which turns the OP's expression into an approximation for $b\approx2$:
$$
_1 F_1(a,b;z)=\frac{(1-b)(b+z-2)}{(a-b+1)z}{_1}F_1(a,b-1;z)+\frac{(1-b)(2-b)}{(a-b+1)z}\frac{a z}{b-2}{_1}F_1(a+1,2;z)+O(b-2)\\
=-\frac{1}{a-1}{_1}F_1(a,1;z)+\frac{a}{a-1}{_1}F_1(a+1,2;z)+O(b-2)\\
$$
and from this we get the $b=2$ case:
$$
_1 F_1(a,2;z)=-\frac{1}{a-1}{_1}F_1(a,1;z)+\frac{a}{a-1}{_1}F_1(a+1,2;z)
$$

## derivation of the approximation used

For $c\approx0$,
$$
_1F_1(a,c;z) = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_k}{(c)_k}\frac{z^k}{k!}
= 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_k}{(k-1)!c}\frac{z^k}{k!}+O(1)
$$
where I have used the approximation $(c)_k=(k-1)!c+O(c^2)$ for $k\ge1$:

```
Series[Pochhammer[c, k], {c, 0, 1}]
(*    Gamma[k] c + O[c]^2    *)
```

Summing analytically,

```
1 + Sum[Pochhammer[a,k]/((k - 1)! c) z^k/k!, {k, 1, ∞}]
(*    1 + (a z Hypergeometric1F1[1 + a, 2, z])/c    *)
```

gives the approximation used, to order $O(1)$. Let's test it with random parameters:

```
With[{a = 1.3, z = 0.47},
  Plot[{c*Hypergeometric1F1[a, c, z], 
        a*z*Hypergeometric1F1[1 + a, 2, z]}, {c, -0.1, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

Seems to work for the limit $c\to0$.

Comment: Can you explain $$ _1F_1(a,c;z) = \frac{a z}{c}{_1}F_1(a+1,2;z)+O(1) $$ and "which turns the OP's expression into an approximation for b≈2" in details? TIA.

Comment: `Limit[(1 - b)*(2 - b)/((a - b + 1)*z)*Hypergeometric1F1[a, b - 2, z],   b -> 2` results in `0`. Did you read "see the limit of the second term is well defined and it is 0" in the question

Comment: Unfortunately, your "Summing analytically" is built on the sand.

Comment: @user64494 you are only adding noise. Do you have anything correct and/or constructive to say?

Comment: Roman (@ does not work.): Please, be correct. Your " you are only adding noise" is not grounded and polite. I repeat "`Limit[(1 - b)*(2 - b)/((a - b + 1)*z)*Hypergeometric1F1[a, b - 2, z],   b -> 2]` results in `0`. Did you read "see the limit of the second term is well defined and it is 0" in the question ".

Comment: That `Limit` result is not correct. If memory serves it arises from an inability of `Series` to expand these hypergeometrics in the parameters.

Comment: Also, @user64494 (@ works just fine): What is the issue you raise with the analysis in this response? The claimed approximation is summable, and the error terms it gives are easily seen to be finite for fixed `{a,z}`.

Comment: @Roman Thank you for your answer. I now have to investigate if your approximation is helpful within my context, but nevertheless I am marking it as the accepted answer. This goes a little beyond my mathematical knowledge, so I can't add more to the discussion.

Comment: What is the correct value of the limit then?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Apparently it errors out if you do FullSimplify first. NLimit also fails, BTW. Limit[(1 - b)*(2 - b)/((a - b + 1)*z)*Hypergeometric1F1[a, b - 2, z] //FullSimplify,   b -> 2]

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников
 `In[289]:= Limit[
 FullSimplify[(1 - b)*(2 - b)/((a - b + 1)*z)*
   Hypergeometric1F1[a, b - 2, z]], b -> 2]

Out[289]= (a z HypergeometricPFQ[{1 + a}, {2}, z])/(-z + a z)` The reason for the erroneous 0 result without `FullSimplify` is that the expression becomes of the form "explicit zero" times "hidden infinity". It strikes me as a deficiency in the implementation of `Hypergeometric1F1` rather than `Limit` or `Series` (which is used by `Limit`).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Oops, my command does not error out. How did I make such a mistake, LOL? Yep. BTW, did you see this, it makes sense to implement as general convergence check https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110324/82985

Comment: @user64494 Yep. Imagine that.